# bigquery table partition programatically using php

Tags: php, google-bigquery, partitioning

I am trying to create partition on big-query when load data using php script but not getting right solution.

```
<?php
require_once '/v/vv/vv/common.php';
require_once '/vv/vv/vv/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;
use Google\Cloud\Core\ExponentialBackoff;
/** Uncomment and populate these variables in your code */
$projectId  = 'id';
$datasetId  = 'ids';

$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
   'projectId' => $projectId,
]);
$dataset = $bigQuery->dataset($datasetId);
$table_id='test_table';
$table = $dataset->table($table_id);
// create the import job
$schema = [
  'fields' => [
        ['name' => 'date', 'type' => 'Date','mode'=>'required'],
        ['name' => 'name', 'type' => 'string'],
        ['name' => 'post_abbr', 'type' => 'string']
  ],
 'timePartitioning'=>['type'=>'DAY','filed'=>'date']
]
```

Comment: Please explain what is not working and share more details

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the [schema definition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#tableschema) with [timePartitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#timepartitioning). Here is a snippet of code:

```php
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;

$source = 'miData.csv';
$datasetId  = 'miDataset';
$table_id='miTable';

$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient();
$dataset = $bigQuery->dataset($datasetId);
$table = $dataset->table($table_id);

$loadConfig = $table->load(fopen($source, 'r'));

$loadConfig->sourceFormat('CSV');

// create the import job
$schema = [
  'fields' => [
        ['name' => 'miDate', 'type' => 'DATE','mode'=>'required'],
        ['name' => 'name', 'type' => 'STRING'],
        ['name' => 'post_abbr', 'type' => 'STRING']
  ]
];

$loadConfig->schema($schema);

$timePartitioning = ['type'=>'DAY','filed'=>'miDate'];
$loadConfig->timePartitioning($timePartitioning);

$loadConfig->createDisposition('CREATE_IF_NEEDED');
$loadConfig->writeDisposition('WRITE_TRUNCATE');


$job = $table->runJob($loadConfig);
```

For more information about the available options for load jobs check the [API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobconfigurationload) and the PHP [loadJobConfiguration](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.106.1/bigquery/loadjobconfiguration).